# when is a point on a curve that minimizes the distance to another given point (that is not on the curve) unique?

Tags: calculus, optimization, euclidean-geometry

If anybody has any useful references (or even the solution) for this problem, it would be much appreciated.

Suppose I have a smooth, closed-curve $S$ that lies in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $s \in S$ be a point on the curve. Given a point $P$ that lies inside $S$ (so $S$ encloses $P$), what are the conditions on $P$ (and possibly $S$) such that there is exactly one $s$ that minimizes the distance $|P-s|$?

In other words, if $d(P,s) = |P - s|$ (Euclidean distance) and $s \in S$ is treated as a variable with $P$ fixed, under what conditions does $d(P,s)$ have a unique global minimum with respect to $s$?

Note that I am not asking about uniqueness of the minimum distance, but the uniqueness of the minimizing point. Obviously, if $S$ is a circle and $P$ is its center, then there are infinitely many points on $s \in S$ that minimize the distance $d(P,s)$. The minimizing distance (the radius) is unique but the points are not. If $P$ is not the center, and still remains strictly inside the circle, the $s$ that minimizes $d(P,s)$ becomes unique.

Heuristically, I would expect a unique global minimum if $P$ lies close enough to $S$. For example, if it was within a radius of curvature, the unique, minimizing $s$ would be found by dropping a perpendicular.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the curve $S$ has no constraints, I think the only condition that there be a unique shortest distance from $P$ to $S$ is that... well... there is a unique shortest distance from $P$ to $S$.

Comment: It seems like you're really asking "When does a closed boundary have a unique point closest to a given point" (i.e. you want the point to be unique, not the distance).  If this is the case, it might be worth editing the title to make this clear.

Comment: Is this question just due to misunderstanding the words used? The "minimum distance" from a point to anything is a **number**.  Given two different number one must be **larger** than the other.  If there were two different number that were claimed to be the "minimum distance", one would have to be larger than the other so could NOT be "minimum".

Comment: @HelloWorld:  Your question is poorly written and ambiguous, as you can see from the numerous correct answers that seem to be not what you're seeking.  Please re-write your question if you want help.

Answer (score -1):

If $S$ was a circle and $P$ was in the center, every point of $S$ would be a minimizing point, even though it is within the radius of curvature, if that was, what you mean.

Comment: No, "every point of S" would NOT be "a minimum" because the question asked about distance and points are N0T "distance".  Every point on a circle, of radius R, would have distance R from the center.  That distance is unique.

Comment: I assumed, the TO meant minimizing points, because the distance to a closed set always exists and is unique. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes I broadly agree. I think the radius of curvature is the threshold in the sense that once you are within a distance strictly less than the radius of curvature, the minimizing point becomes unique.

Answer (score -1):

"when is the minimum distance from a point to a closed boundary unique?"

Always, of course.

(How could it possibly be otherwise?)

If your question is instead "when is the *point* on a curve closest to a given point not on the curve unique?" then there is no general answer.  You must test every point (or make explicit model of the curve and the non-curve point.

Comment: +1 for the "question badly worded, answer technically correct" angle.

Comment: Consider a circle and its center.

Comment: @JulianMejia read the question carefully. $\min\neq\arg\!\min$.

Comment: @JulianMejia:  For a circle and its center:  THE MINIMUM DISTANCE (r) ***IS UNIQUE***.  Understand?

Comment: Sure, it is not well written, but then he writes it in other words. Here he refers to having a "unique point" that is at the minimum distance from $P$.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous title, but thanks to all those that replied. Yes, I am talking about the uniqueness of points that minimize the distance. I have updated the title and discussed the simple case of a circle. Hopefully that clears it up.